# How to use lossless compression with WP_Image_Editor

Tags: images, compression

I am using WP_Image_Editor through the Timber plugin and it's [TimberImageHelper](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/blob/master/lib/timber-image-helper.php) class. In my theme code I have: `TimberImageHelper::resize($path,$w,$h,$cropArea);`, which eventually (after various manipulations of the filename and math to do with resizing and cropping) boils down to something like this :

```
$image = wp_get_image_editor( $load_filename );
$image->crop( $src_x, 0, $src_wt, $src_h, $w, $h );
$result = $image->save( $save_filename );
```

Google page insights is currently telling me I ought to be losslessly compressing my images, with most reporting optimizations of roughly 50%. This is a big difference and I want to pursue it, but I can't see a good way to use lossless compression with the TimberImageHelper OR with WP_Image_Editor directly so far.

I know I can filter the default quality to be used when resizing but I have the impression (correct me if it's wrong) that this is lossy compression and will bomb the image quality.

I've seen that there are the EWWW, TinyPNG/JPG and kraken.io plugins and have read a few articles about them. I guess they are an option, however currently the site is designed for late image manipulations (various pages use a wide array of sizes of images, which are created on demand rather than on upload), which have some logic in PHP to work on non-standard crop fits and such. Basically, if it were a plugin I would like it to be one that is totally unobtrusive in Wordpress other than offering me some calls (similar to TimberImageHelper::resize) that I can call. I guess I am more looking for a library than a WP Plugin.

Is there a way to achieve this with the default WP_Image_Editor that I have missed (or should I just be using the 1-100 quality filter)? Is there a good library/plugin etc that will give me the methods/functions to achieve lossless compression and resizing, without making other changes or introducing other filters/actions to the wordpress ecosystem to change image functions directly?

Comment: Might be worth a read - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/ it references https://github.com/ResponsiveImagesCG/wp-tevko-responsive-images#advanced-image-compression for WP

Answer (score 0):

With @jgraup 's help in comments, I had a look at the responsive images plugin linked there. While that particular one has several other filters on things like post content which I would have preferred not to use, the RespImg class included is exactly what I was wanting. I was originally considering what would be required to remove all the filters added by the plugin... it's only 5 or 6, however I found a more barebones version of the same class here: https://github.com/nwtn/wp-respimg . It does not include any of the filters other than the one to add that editor class, and dropped into my project nicely.